# TeamCity Programmatically Build Branch

Tags: teamcity

How do I get TeamCity to programmatically build from a specific branch?

In my use case I am trying to run a test suite against multiple environments. I have two TeamCity jobs. The first job will hit an endpoint to get the build version on the environment. The second job will check out the branch matching this build version and run my test suite.

I have a solution where I would checkout the correct branch as a build step but I feel like this is the wrong way. I feel like there should be an option in the Version Control Settings regarding which branch to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [feature branches support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/working-with-feature-branches.html) in TeamCity. [Specify a branch spec](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/working-with-feature-branches.html#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Configuringbranches) in VCS root, and when starting a build you can select on which branch you want to run it.